# Хранение номера телефона в контексте закона о персональных данных

Tags: хранение-данных, персональные-данные

Есть мобильное приложение некоего волонтерского движения.
Есть необходимость предоставлять координаторам движения номера телефонов участников (тех, кто не против).

1) Фактически, насколько я понял, хранение этих номеров в БД приложения превращает автора в оператора персданных. Или нет?

2) Передача номера третьим лицам - нарушение закона

У кого есть опыт в подобного рода делах, как это все дело организовать правильно?

Как сделать "подписание разрешения", чтобы было по закону?

**UPD**
Процесс построен таким образом:

1. Волонтер создает алерт - "там то и тогда то произошло такое то событие"
2. Происходит нотификация всех подписанных. Кто может - выезжает на место для оказания помощи
3. Иногда, когда предоставленной информации явно недостаточно, координатору нужна возможность позвонить и уточнить детали

Волонтеров много - лично передавать свой номер координаторам(их тоже не очень чтоб мало) так себе не вариант, к сожалению.

PS На всякий случай - никакой политики и ничего противозаконного.

Comment: *Есть необходимость предоставлять координаторам движения номера телефонов участников (тех, кто не против).* Чтобы не связываться с означенным законом, нужно, чтобы сам владелец телефона инициативно предоставлял его этому самому координатору. Тогда этот процесс ничем не отличается от обычного сообщения своего номера родственнику/знакомому/коллеге, а хранение им этого номера телефона в приложении ничем не отличается от хранения телефона родственника/знакомого/коллеги в штатном приложении "Контакты". В общем, исключите передачу **чужого** номера телефона, и всё...

Comment: @Akina обновил вопрос.

Comment: На шаге 2 "Происходит нотификация всех подписанных", я так понимаю, у волонтера появляется кнопка "откликнуться". Там же можно добавить галочку "передать мой номер телефона"